# Double integral with non constant limits in quadpy?

Tags: python, integration, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I need to integrate a function defined in 2Dims (`z` and radius `r`), for which I don't have an expression.

I can just query the function at any position `(z,r)` and get the returned value.

I have the integration range across z: `[-z_range, z_range]`, which I partition into `N_z` points as:

```
z_is = -z_range + (np.arange(N_z) + 0.5) * (2.*z_range/N_z)
```

For each value in `z_is`, the range to integrate across `r` is: `[0, r_thresh_at_this_z]`.

`r_thresh_at_this_z` is obtained from the value of `z` called `z_i` as:

```
def get_r_thresh(z_i):
    return expression_of_z_i # returns a positive float.
```

So the range on the radial integral is dependent on the value on `z`.

I have the function f as:

```
def f(r,z):
    return interpolator_for_f(r,z)
```

I want to use the `quadpy` package in the most efficient way as it has been created to be able to be used in this way.

I was thinking to use a for loop to loop through the `z_is` and to perform a gaussian quadrature across `[0, r_thres_for_that_z]`, for each value in `z_is`.

I could use:

```
results = np.zeros((N_z))
errs = np.zeros((N_z))
for i in range(N_z):
   def f(r):
      return interpolator_for_f(r,z_is[i])
   results[i], errs[i] = quadpy.quad(f, [0, r_thresh_at_this_z])
```

But I feel a for loop is not the most efficient way to use quadpy.

Can you tell me what I am missing in doing this integral only with fast numpy arrays, so no for-loops?

[I have read about the shapes of the input `x` to the function `f`.
In my case `d = 1` because it's a line integral across r.
`n = N_z` because I want to perform `N_z` such line integrals which I will then add up to obtain 1 single scalar, the result of the (whole) double integral.

`p = 1000` because say I want 1000 integration points across `r`, for each value of `z`.

So I will need to sample the function at `N_z * 1000` points.

Function `f` shall return an array shaped `(N_z, 1000)`

Is the identification of these parameters helpful in any way?]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Quadpy author here.

> I want to use the quadpy package in the most efficient way as it has been created to be able to be used in this way.

That's not the case. Quadpy helps integrating functions in all kinds of canonical domains, but the functionality to integrate over an arbitray 2D domains isn't there yet. doublequad/nquad is something that should be in quadpy, but isn't yet.

Comment: Could I use the set composed of tuples like (result +- error) obtained at each z value (so at equidistant points across the z-axis) from quadpy c1 adaptive integration to do perform a 1D integration (from those samples) across z? To get the total error estimate of the 2D integral, I need to estimate the error on this 1D z-integral for it's [integral of results] part, but also for it's [integral of errors] part, and then to add the moduli of these 2 error estimates? These 2 error estimates depend on the 1D integration scheme I use. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't catch that.

Comment: one 1Dim quadpy adaptive gaussian gives 2 floats, result and error. I do this adaptive integration for each value of z. I store results and errors in 2 arrays, each shaped (N_z,). I then perform midpoint rule in 1Dim using the values from the results array. I also do midpoint rule in 1Dim using the values from the errors array. I estimate maximum error on midpoint rule using maximum value of 2nd derivate (calculated numerically). I add the 2 moduli of the maximum errors from the midpoint rule for results and from the midpoint rule for errors. This is the total error for the whole 2D integral.